# Python Creating Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, plot

So I am writing a code to simulate Conway's "Game of Life." I've managed to mostly implement the game, however, there's an extra step that I am missing

I have handled everything except the logic for determining if a cell is alive or dead. We are using numpy arrays to store 1's and 0's with 1 being considered alive and 0 being considered dead.

Is there any way that I would be able to loop through the array and print whether a cell is alive or dead, or some form of this?

Here is my code.

For initial creation.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from time import sleep

def update_plot(array, figsize=(7,5), title=''):
    clear_output(wait=False)
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    plt.imshow(array,cmap="gray")
    plt.title(title)
    #plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Remember alive is white, dead is black')
    plt.show();
```

Then, this is for starting the game.

```
def startup(random_percent=None):
    size_to_build = input("enter the size of your game of life\n")
    dimension = int(size_to_build)
    ##Build the game board, bias is an optional parameter you can pass the function
    if random_percent==None:
        game_board = np.random.randint(2,size=(dimension,dimension))
    else:
        game_board = np.arange(dimension**2)
        #In place shuffle
        np.random.shuffle(game_board)
        #Grab number we should make alive
        alive = int(np.floor(len(game_board)*random_percent))
        #Set those elements to be alive
        zeros = np.zeros(dimension**2)
        alive_cells = game_board[0:alive:1]
        zeros[alive_cells]=1
        game_board = zeros.reshape(dimension,-1)
    return game_board
```

And this is for running the game.

```
def game_of_life():
    start_board = startup()
    board = start_board
    count = 1
    not_stable = True

    while not_stable:
        title_plot="This is iteration number: " + str(count)
        update_plot(board,title=title_plot)
        board_prev = board
        board = update_game_board(board)
        if np.array_equal(board_prev,board):
            not_stable = False
        sleep(2)
        count+=1
    print("Stable game conditions reached after:",count,"iterations")
```

This is the function I am attempting to refine.

```
def update_game_board(input_board):

for element in input_board:
     print("Alive Or Dead")





    return np.logical_not(input_board)*1
```

How would I access to the "dead" and Alive" elements in the array?

I'm rather new to numpy and python and have only worked with it scarcely. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnColeman Fixed the information. Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to achieve this for beginners is to loop through the NumPy array one element at a time and compute the sum of it's neighboring elements.  You did not specify the boundary conditions, so I assumed periodic boundaries (i.e. the world wraps around on the top/bottom and left/right).

You can access the shape of the array using NumPy's "shape" function, which will tell you how many rows and columns (though they're equal in your specification) are in the array.  You can also create a like-sized array of all zeros using NumPy's "zeros_like" function.

```
def update_game_board(board):

    new_board = np.zeros_like(board)
    r, r = np.shape(board)

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(r):

            neighbors = [[i,j],
                         [i,j+1],
                         [i,j-1],
                         [i+1,j],
                         [i-1,j],
                         [i+1,j+1],
                         [i+1,j-1],
                         [i-1,j+1],
                         [i-1,j-1]]

            neighbor_sum = 0

            # Let's count all of the living neighbors
            for n in neighbors:

                x = n[0] % r
                y = n[1] % r

                neighbor_sum += board[x,y]

            if board[i,j] == 1:
                if neighbor_sum in [2,3]:
                    new_board[i,j] = 1
            else:
                if neighbor_sum == 3:
                    new_board[i,j] = 1

    return new_board
```

Once you're more comfortable with Python and NumPy arrays, you can play with different boundary conditions or more efficient ways to compute the updated board.